# Android: How to disable notification channel programmatically?

Tags: android, notifications, notification-channel

I have a working implementation, to check if a channel is enabled.

But is there any possible way to **disable** a notification channel programmatically?

How I check if the channel is enabled:

```
    /**
     * Get the setting a user has applied to the notification channel.
     * If the android API level is < 26, it will return true if all notification
     * are enabled in general, false otherwise.
     *
     * @return true if the channel is enabled, false otherwise
     */
    public static boolean isChannelEnabled(String channelId) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            final NotificationManager notificationManager = App.get().getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            if (notificationManager == null) {
                return true;
            } else {
                final NotificationChannel c = notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(channelId);
                final boolean overallEnabled = notificationManager.areNotificationsEnabled();
                return overallEnabled && c != null && NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE != c.getImportance();
            }
        } else {
            return NotificationManagerCompat.from(App.get()).areNotificationsEnabled();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try channel.getImportance() = IMPORTANCE_NONE;

Comment: @KristyWelsh that's so crazy I had to reply to a 3 year old comment. You're trying to assign a value to a function?

Comment: @Niall Yes that won't be possible ;) But you can create the channel at app start up and use `IMPORTANCE_NONE` in the NotificationChannel ctor. That does actually work and disable the channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **Kristy Welsh** mentioned, it is possible to disable a channel by setting
the importance of the channel to `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE`.

As the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#createNotificationChannel(android.app.NotificationChannel)) of `NotificationManager.createNotificationChannel` states:

> This can also be used to restore a deleted channel and to **update** an existing channel's name, description, group, and/or importance. (...)
> The importance of an existing channel **will only be changed if the new importance is lower** than the current value and the user has not altered any settings on this channel.

Note: *So it is indeed possible to disable a channel. But it won't be possible to set it back to some higher importance.*

Some pseudo code:

```kotlin
val channel = NotificationChannel(someId, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE).apply { /* ... */ }
val notificationManager = application.getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
notificationManager.createNotificationChannelGroup(channel)
```

I need to say, that I do not need this "feature" anymore, but
I have tested it anyway on Pixel 7 and Android 13.
For me it was possible to degrade the importance to disable the channel.
It's not possible to enable the channel again afterwards programmatically.
(See docu above).